# Composing functions with multiple arrow functions

Tags: javascript, currying

Looking at the compose function (taken from Redux)

```
function compose(...funcs) {
    if (funcs.length === 0) {
      return arg => arg
    }

    if (funcs.length === 1) {
      return funcs[0]
    }

    return funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
  }

const double = x => x * 2
const square = x => x * x
const double1 = x => x * 3
compose(double, square, double1)(5)
```

in the last return statement

```
funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
```

What is the purpose of returning a functions that takes `..args`, why not just have

```
funcs.reduce((a, b) => a(b(...args))) ?
```

Comment: `compose(double, square, double1)(5)` <- its the `(5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your suggested variant you will have return the result of the `a(b(...args))`, where you haven't pass the `args`. So you will get a compile error that `args` is not defined.

But in the upper variant it returns a function, which takes parameters (`args` -
 `5` is passed as `args`) and returns the result of `a(b(...args))` like

```
(...args) => a(b(...args))
```

Look at this example. It is showing the difference with two approaches.

```js
function a(str) {
  console.log('In a');
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

function b(str) {
  console.log('In b');
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

const message = a(b('text')); // This is your variant. Immediate result.
console.log(`Message is ${message}`);

const func = (someText) => a(b(someText)); // This is the given variant. Need to call `func` to get the result.

const anotherMessage = func('anotherText'); Here I need to call `func` and pass my parameter to it.
console.log(`Message is ${anotherMessage}`);
```